# How to make a discord bot find, and move to the current voice channel of a specific user

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've been playing around with making fun discord bots for my friends, and we had the idea to create a bot that every 10 seconds checks the location of one of our friends and follows him to whatever voice chat he joins.

I've been unable to sort through the [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) documentation to figure out even how to join a voice channel.

Please help, the documentation is absolutely horrid to search through compared to any other I've used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join a [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voicechannel), you can just use the [`VoiceChannel.connect`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.connect) function.

Bot accounts cannot have friends on Discord. What do you call "friends"? Are there just user accounts you defined in your code? Your question isn't very clear.

Here is my answer to your question, as I understand it:

```py
import discord
import asyncio

friends = [] # Here you put the IDs of the people you consider as friends

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    channel = after.channel # Voice channel
    bot_connection = member.guild.voice_client # Bot connection

    if channel and member.id in friends: # If a friend connected to a voice channel
        if bot_connection:
            # Move to new channel if bot was connected to a previous one
            await bot_connection.move_to(channel)
        else:
            # If bot was not connected, connect it
            await channel.connect()

    if not channel and bot_connection: # Disconnect if member has left
        await bot_connection.disconnect()
```

I here used the [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update) event, and I checked if the id of the `member` is in the `friends` list, and if the `member` is in a voice channel now.

Comment: Hi I've tried using this but have been unable to get the bot to join. I have managed to get the error message to send but I'm unable to figure out why the bot can't join the channel. It has been given administrator permissions in a test server and will just give the error message as defined in the code, with the correct channel name.

Comment: I fixed the error I had actually but now I'm struggling to figure out how to make the bot disconnect when the user it's meant to follow disconnects. I've tried checking if channel == None but that returns 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: I initally accepted this answer but I'm now facing the issue that if the user moves from one channel to another, the bot will join that channel and then immediately disconnect. This seems to happen even if the code telling the bot to disconnect is commented out so there is some error elsewhere causing it.

Comment: Yes. Copying your code exactly (just adding my discord token to run it), if I move between more than two channels, it will alternate between joining successfully or joining then immediately leaving, back and forth each time I reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not that bad. I don't really use Python but I can try and point you in the right direction based on other knowledge of the Discord API.

I would expect an API wrapper to store a user's voice channel in its `Member` object - the `Member` contains info about a user relating to a specific server.

So I browsed to the docs for [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member)...
And here there is a [`voice` property](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.voice)... (contains the member's voice state)
Which has a [`channel` property](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState.channel)...
Which has a [`connect()` method](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.connect).

Putting that all together, you simply need to obtain your friend's `Member` object, then call `member.voice.channel.connect()`. The `connect()` method is a coroutine which returns a [`VoiceClient`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient) which you can use to play audio if you so desire.

For obtaining your friend's `Member` object you'll want your server's ID and your friend's ID. Then simply use [`Client.get_guild(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild) and call [`Guild.get_member(id)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member) on the result.

Comment: I will note that this answer was written to guide the asker to the solution for "checking a user's voice channel every 10 seconds and joining it", the other answer correctly identifies that doing this on the voice update event would be a much better solution and you should do that instead!